# Counting record rows with HAVING GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is (maybe) a bit complex, I try to write it down comprehensible.
I have a Class in PHP which generates a MySQL query depending on several circumstances and parameters (then displays the query result in a dinamyc table). 
For example here are the tables and an example query:

[image: table relations]

It is simple, There are users, and each user can have one or more profiles assigned.
For exmaple we have only one user and he has two profiles:

```
[USER]
userid    login     password     status    reg_date
------    -------   ----------   ------    -------------------
1         JohnDoe   hd98349...   0         2014-01-09 16:00:55

[PROFILE]
profile_id  profile_name    
----------  ------------
1           admin
2           root
3           user

[USER_PROFILE]
relation_id   user   profile
-----------   -----  -------
1             1      1
2             1      2
```

My PHP code generates a query that looks like this for example:

```sql
SELECT 
    userid AS 'User id', 
    login AS 'User name', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Profile(s)', 
    `status`  
FROM `user` LEFT JOIN user_profile ON `user`.userid = user_profile.`user`
         LEFT JOIN `profile` ON user_profile.`profile` = `profile`.profile_id  
WHERE 
    status IN (0, 1) 
ORDER BY reg_date ASC 
LIMIT 0 ,10
```

And the result for this query is:

```
[RESULT]
User id    User name    Profile(s)   status
-------    ---------    ----------   ------
1          JohnDoe      root, admin  0
```

When I want to use filters on a column that is originated from a subquery or a complex expression (like the `GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ')`) I get false result:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'all_rows'  
FROM `user` LEFT JOIN user_profile ON `user`.userid = user_profile.`user`
      LEFT JOIN `profile` ON user_profile.`profile` = `profile`.profile_id  WHERE          status IN (0, 1) 
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') LIKE '%root%'
```

This will result in: 'all_rows' => 2.
This is because the GROUP_CONCAT in the HAVING won't group, but If I put it in the SELECT like: SELECT COUNT(GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ')) I get an error

So the question is how could I get the number of all rows using a GROUP_CONCAT in a filter (WHERE / HAVING) expression?

EDIT: Before I run the main query I need to know how many record rows would it result, without the LIMIT restriction. I use this to calculate the start row value for the LIMIT for pagination purposes.

Comment: Can you set this up on SQL Fiddle (www.sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Personally, I tend to avoid GROUP_CONCAT (and CONCAT) altogether. I prefer to handle those aspects of a given problem at the application level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GROUP\_CONCAT() row count when grouping by a text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862968/group-concat-row-count-when-grouping-by-a-text-field)

Comment: You don't have a `GROUP BY` clause in your queries. So you're aggregating all the rows that match the `WHERE` condition into a single result.

Comment: Doesn't the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option solve the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

can you try the outcome of this one? You're not telling the query engine what to group for and it seems it's guessing wrong.

```
SELECT `user`.userid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') as roles,
    COUNT(*) AS 'all_rows'  
FROM `user` 
    LEFT JOIN user_profile ON `user`.userid = user_profile.`user`
    LEFT JOIN `profile` ON user_profile.`profile` = `profile`.profile_id  
WHERE          status IN (0, 1) 
GROUP BY `user`.userid
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') LIKE '%root%'
```

Comment: the answer is still the same my friend..its 2

Answer (score 0):

You have an unusual query where the count would return either 0 or 1.  You can definitely fix this problem by using a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'all_rows'  
FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') as pns
      FROM `user` LEFT JOIN
           user_profile
           ON `user`.userid = user_profile.`user` LEFT JOIN
           `profile`
           ON user_profile.`profile` = `profile`.profile_id
      WHERE status IN (0, 1) 
     ) t
WHERE pns LIKE '%root%';
```

You can also fix the problem by moving the logic to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `user` LEFT JOIN
     user_profile
     ON `user`.userid = user_profile.`user` LEFT JOIN
     `profile`
     ON user_profile.`profile` = `profile`.profile_id
WHERE status IN (0, 1) and profile_name like '%root%';
```

Comment: These are good ideas and they should work, but in my case the query is generated dinamycally and cannot distinct the original columns from columns that are results of a subquery or a complex expression. My class handles all columns in the SELECT part together, so I cannot put the GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') part away form the others.

Answer (score 0):

I fond a solution:
This is how record counting query looks:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'all_rows' 
FROM (SELECT 
         userid AS 'User id', 
         login AS 'User name',    
         GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Profile(s)', 
         status  
      FROM `user` LEFT JOIN user_profile ON `user`.userid = user_profile.`user` 
            LEFT JOIN `profile` ON user_profile.`profile` = `profile`.profile_id  
      HAVING 
          status IN (0,    1) 
          AND  GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') LIKE '%root%') t
```

And this is the main query:

```sql
SELECT 
    userid AS 'User id', 
    login AS 'User name', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Profil(ok)', 
    status  
FROM `user` LEFT JOIN user_profile ON `user`.userid = user_profile.`user`
            LEFT JOIN `profile` ON user_profile.`profile` = `profile`.profile_id  
HAVING 
    status IN (0, 1) 
    AND  GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') LIKE '%root%'  
ORDER BY reg_date ASC 
LIMIT 0 ,10
```

I have to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` everywhere, because as I said the main query is generated programically. This is how I set the columns in the SELECT part:

```
$listObj->setColumns(array('userid' => 'User id',
               'login'  => 'User name',
               'GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR \', \')' => 'Profile(s)'));
```

And when a user types the %root% expression in the filter input referring to the `GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Profile(s)'` column I cannot decide if `GROUP_CONCAT(profile_name SEPARATOR ', ') LIKE %root%` goes into the `WHERE` part or the `HAVING` part because it is handled together with any other columns (like the 
`userid AS 'User id'` or the `login AS 'User name'` columns)

The remaining technically question is that isn't it a mistake to use `HAVING` everywhere, even when a simple `WHERE` would be enough?